# scanf() only reading first input (number)

Tags: c, scanf

I can't really explain it except that `scanf()` is only reading the first value, and then the calculations are made based off of that.

```
int main() {
    int i, students = 0;
    char name[20];
    int tests;
    float test_score;
    int test_sum = 0;
    char letter_grade;
    double test_average;

    printf("Number of students: ");
    scanf("%d", &students);

    for (i = 0; i < students; i++) {
        printf("\nStudent name %d: ", i + 1);
        scanf(" %s", &name);
        fflush(stdin);

        printf("Number of test(s) for %s: ", name);
        scanf("%d", &tests);
        fflush(stdin);

        printf("Enter %d test score(s) for %s: ", tests, name);
        if (i < students) {
            scanf("%f", &test_score);
            test_sum += test_score;
            test_average = test_sum / (float)tests;
        }
        printf("Average test score: %.2f", test_average);

        fflush(stdin);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Say I enter 2 students, the first student with 2 test scores, then enter 45 87. I should be getting 66.00, but I'm getting 22.50. For the second student, I'd enter 3 test scores of 100 55 87, and I get 48.33. Waaayyy off.

I know I'm doing something wrong, but I can't figure out, because I had it working before, but the loop wouldn't continue to the second student.

Comment: Do you know what `fflush(stdin)` does?

Comment: `if (i < students) {` --> for(int j = 0; j < tests; ++j){` and reset variables(`test_sum`) after this loop.

Comment: @EOF Clears the buffer. When I don't include it, my program ends. I do see how redundant it is, but I don't know why my code won't stand without them.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Tried that, but I get errors like missing } and ), which is really weird.

Comment: @DSmith: In standard, portable, C, `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior. POSIX and windows define behavior for it, but I'm not aware of any situation where it is in any way useful.

Comment: try `int i, j, students = 0;` then `int j = 0` --> `j = 0`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY It worked! Thank you!!

Comment: this line: `scanf(" %s", &name);` is not correct.  In C, a reference to an array name degrades to the address of the first address of the array.  `name` is the name of an array.  Therefore, the line should be: `scanf(" %s", name);` Notice not `&` before the array name

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings. (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` )   Note: there are several places in the code where  a `float` value is being assigned an `int` variable, which will drop any fractional part.  Is this what you actually want to do?

Comment: this line: `if (i < students) {`  is not correct.  1) 'i' will always be less than 'students'   2) what is really wanted is a loop to allow the entry of several student scores.  Suggest: `for( int  j = 0; j < tests; j++ )

Comment: this line: `test_average = test_sum / (float)tests;` should not be performed until after all the student test scores are entered.  Suggest moving that line to after the loop that inputs the test scores AND writing it similar to: `double test_sum = 0.0; ... test_average = test_sum / tests;`

Comment: @EOF Correction: POSIX does not define what happens if you `fflush()` a stream whose last operation was reading.

Comment: @FUZxxl: [Does too!](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) *For a stream open for reading with an underlying file description, if the file is not already at EOF, and the file is one capable of seeking, the file offset of the underlying open file description shall be set to the file position of the stream, and any characters pushed back onto the stream by ungetc() or ungetwc() that have not subsequently been read from the stream shall be discarded (without further changing the file offset).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (i < students) {
     scanf("%f", &test_score);
     test_sum += test_score;
     test_average = test_sum / (float)tests;
}
```

Should be :

```
test_sum = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < tests; j++) {
    scanf("%f", &test_score);
    test_sum += test_score;
}
test_average = test_sum / (float)tests;
```

Comment: This seems to be the only way to get the right calculation, but my program ends right after and it doesn't reach student #2. I also removed fflush(stdin). I've been going in circles for a couple of hours...

Comment: test_sum variable should be set to 0 before for loop

Answer (score 1):

You always need to check the return value of `scanf()` to see how many tokens it read.  If it fails to read, you need to take corrective action.

It's not clear why you'd need `fflush(stdin)` every time.

Answer (score 1):

the posted code contains several problems including

1. can only enter one test score
2. random mix of `int` and `float` and `double` variables
3. incorrect format strings for calls to `scanf()`
4. a number of unused variables
5. failure to check for errors on calls to `scanf()`
6. poor variable naming.  Variable names should indicate content or usage (or better both)
7. calling `fflush(stdin)` is specifically listed as undefined behaviour in the C standard
8. test_sum is not re-initialized between students

The following proposed code fixes all the above problems and compiles cleanly

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  // exit(),  EXIT_FAILURE

// prototypes
void flushStdin( void );

int main( void )
{
    int  numStudents = 0;
    char studentName[20];
    int  numTests;

    double test_score;
    double test_sum = 0.0;
    //char   letter_grade;
    double test_average;

    printf("Number of students: ");
    if( 1 != scanf("%d", &numStudents) )
    { // then scanf failed
        perror( "scanf for number of students failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, scanf successful

    flushStdin();

    for (int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++)
    {
        printf("\nStudent name %d: ", i + 1);
        if( 1 != scanf(" %s", studentName) )
        { // then scanf failed
            perror( "scanf for student name failed" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, scanf successful

        flushStdin();

        printf("Number of test(s) for %s: ", studentName);
        if( 1 != scanf("%d", &numTests) )
        { // scanf failed
            perror( "scanf for number of tests failed" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, scanf successful

        test_sum = 0.0;
        printf("Enter %d test score(s) for %s: ", numTests, studentName);
        for( int j=0; j<numTests; j++ )
        {
            if( 1 != scanf("%lf", &test_score) )
            { // then scanf failed
                perror( "scanf for test score failed");
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            }

            // implied else, scanf successful

            flushStdin();

            test_sum += test_score;
        }

        test_average = test_sum / numTests;
        printf("Average test score: %.2lf", test_average);
    }
    return 0;
} // end function: main


void flushStdin()
{
    int ch;
    while( (ch = getchar() ) != EOF && '\n' != ch);
}
```